# Why Typescript can't infer type when you assign a return typed method's output to a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, types, interface

I have a reusable service so I have created a public API with documentation and types to ease the usage of clients.

```js
interface Storable {
  setItem(key: string, value: string): any;
  getItem(key: string): string;
  removeItem(key: string): any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStorageService {
   private expirableSecureLocalStorage:any;
   private secureLocalStorage:any;
   private expirableLocalStorage:any;
   constructor(/*...*/) {
    this.expirableSecureLocalStorage = this.createExpirableStorage(this.createSecureStorage(localStorage));
    this.secureLocalStorage = this.createSecureStorage(localStorage);
    this.expirableLocalStorage = this.createExpirableStorage(localStorage);
   }

   /**
   * Returns a handle to localStorage: Use when you want to compose/decorate storages.
   */
  getLocalStore(): Storable {
    return localStorage;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a handle to sesionStorage: Use when you want to compose/decorate storages.
   */
  getSessionStore(): Storable {
    return sessionStorage;
  }
  /** 
   * Recommended: Singleton - prefer for ordinary operations
   */
  getExpirableSecureLocalStorage(): Storable {
    return this.expirableSecureLocalStorage;
  }

  /** 
   * Recommended: Singleton - prefer for ordinary operations
   */
  getSecureLocalStorage(): Storable {
    return this.secureLocalStorage;
  }

  /** 
   * Recommended: Singleton - prefer for ordinary operations
   */
  getExpirableLocalStorage(): Storable {
    return this.expirableLocalStorage;
  }

  //...

}
```

Then in a client:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FeatureService {

  expirableSecureLocalStorage:any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private dataStorageService: DataStorageService) {  
    this.expirableSecureLocalStorage = dataStorageService.getExpirableSecureLocalStorage();                                 
  }
 
  async getFeatures(keyname: string) {
    let features: any;
    let feature: any;
    try {
      let featuresLocalData = this.expirableSecureLocalStorage.getItem("features");
      //...
    }
    //...
   }
```

When this code has evolved to current status, I have realized that when I have added the type `Storable` to `DataStorageService`, vscode's autocomplete/intellisense has started to suggest methods. However, in the client when I keep the method's `dataStorageService.getExpirableSecureLocalStorage()` which returns a `Storable` result in a reference variable `expirableSecureLocalStorage:any` and when I try to use a method of it like `getItem` as `this.expirableSecureLocalStorage.getItem("features")`, vscode does not offer `getItem` and other two methods directly.

Why can't typescript infer the type of the reference variable which is assigned to the result of the method which has a return type?

What should I have to do to make vscode suggest methods that is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't typescript infer the type of the reference variable which is assigned to the result of the method which has a return type?

Because you have *explicitly* told it to *not* infer a type by explicitly *giving the type yourself*.

Comment: Thank you @Jörg W Mittag. Actually I have mostly Java experience and thought that `any` like somehow a super type like `Object` or maybe `void` in C.

Comment: If you have Java experience, then it is exactly the same: if you annotate a variable with a type, then it has that type. *Only* if you tell the compiler (in the case of Java by using the `var` keyword, in the case of TypeScript by leaving out the type) to infer the type, it will infer the type. Yes, `any` is a *top type* like `Object` in Java, that is precisely *why* you don't get any IntelliSense: because you have *told* TypeScript that the type is `any`, which means that it could be anything, so TypeScript *cannot make any assumptions* about it.

Comment: Note that `void` is a *bottom type*, so it is the *exact opposite* of a top type like `Object` or `any`.

Comment: By " in the case of TypeScript by **leaving out the type**" do you mean just changing `expirableSecureLocalStorage:any;` to `expirableSecureLocalStorage`, because in this case AFAIK typescript will assume it `any` and indeed I have tried also?

Comment: `Storable` is not exported, so obviously TypeScript cannot infer it, so `any` is indeed the best possible type it can infer, since it doesn't know anything about `Storable`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code `expirableSecureLocalStorage:any;` tells typescript that whatever you put in `expirableSecureLocalStorage`, it should handle it as "anything", effectively removing its type.

You shoud export your `Storable` interface and declare `expirableSecureLocalStorage` like this:

```
expirableSecureLocalStorage: Storable;
```

Comment: Thank you @known-as-bmf but my question is why it can't infer from the type of `dataStorageService.getExpirableSecureLocalStorage()` which actually returns a storable. Otherwise, as similar to what you said I have to put the interface in a central/global place and probably set `tsconfig.json` to make it global to all the sources preferably as a namespaced type and that is the thing I'm trying to avoid since actually I don't exactly know how and also think that it should not be necessary for this kind of things ultimately because I expect if to infer from the results type.

Comment: Oh, I have realized that you have said "**effectively removing its type**". Why it's removing the type, but don't use it as the type of the variable? Isn't `any` type to be used by typescript to infer its actual type?

Comment: No, it does not work that way. `expirableSecureLocalStorage` will have the type you assign it.

You could create a "local" second type, identical to `Storable` and use this type for your variable but you'll have to do it everywhere you use a `Storable`.

Since this interface/service is designed to be shared / used in multiple places, it would make sense to simply export it from where it is defined and import it from there where you need it.

Comment: Alternatively, put `Storable` in a separate independant file and import it to use it from your services / controllers / whatever. Also: why aren't you using the "native" `Storage` type ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: I may use `Storage`, but since I have only three methods as wrappers even I'm aware of duck typing that my decorators could take the advantage of it and still work fine, I thought that I need to be precise for types not to confuse colleagues who get used to directly use `localStorage` and not using types a lot.